# HTML full width table

Tags: html, css

I want a full width table. When I give `position:fixed;` It becomes full width but scrollable does not work.

In short I need a table without any margin to the body of the browser.

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  zoom: 4.0;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.table {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .table {
    display: block;
  }
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

.row.header {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ea6153;
}

.row.green {
  background: #27ae60;
}

.row.blue {
  background: #2980b9;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .row {
    padding: 8px 0;
    display: block;
  }
}

.cell {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  display: table-cell;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .cell {
    padding: 2px 12px;
    display: block;
  }
}

.cell:before {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  margin: 0 5px 0 -15px;
  content: '\f023';
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Tips and Fair Review
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0` to your body styles.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  zoom: 4.0;
  margin: 0;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.table {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .table {
    display: block;
  }
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
.row.header {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ea6153;
}
.row.green {
  background: #27ae60;
}
.row.blue {
  background: #2980b9;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .row {
    padding: 8px 0;
    display: block;
  }
}
.cell {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  display: table-cell;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .cell {
    padding: 2px 12px;
    display: block;
  }
}
.cell:before {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  margin: 0 5px 0 -15px;
  content: '\f023';
}
```

```html
<div class="table">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Tips and Fair Review
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```